# Get the last part of file name in C#

Tags: c#

I need get last part means the numeric value(318, 319) of the following text (will vary)

```
C:\Uploads\X\X-1\37\Misc_318.pdf
C:\Uploads\X\X-1\37\Misc_ 319.pdf
C:\Uploads\X\C-1\37\Misc _  320.pdf
```

Once I get that value I need to search for the entire folder. Once I find the files name with matching number, I need to remove all spaces and rename the file in that particular folder

Here is What I want

- First get the last part of the file(numeric number may vary)
- Based upon the number I get search in the folder to get all files names
- Once I get the all files name check for spaces with file name and remove the spaces.

Comment: Where is your unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: How many characters do you want to capture? Do you want to capture all number characters at the end of the name, or just the last 3 characters before the extension?

Comment: And what do you mean last part? just the file name? If you mean the file name without the path than Path.GetFileName

Comment: The number is not limited to 3....Yes I need to capture at the end of name

Answer (score 8):

**Finding the Number**

If the naming follows the convention SOMEPATH\SomeText_[Optional spaces]999.pdf, try

```
var file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(thePath);
string[] parts = file.split('_');
int number = int.Parse(parts[1]);
```

Of course, add error checking as appropriate.  You may want to check that there are 2 parts after the split, and perhaps use int.TryParse() instead, depending on your confidence that the file names will follow that pattern and your ability to recover if TryParse() returns false.

**Constructing the New File Name**

I don't fully understand what you want to do once you have the number.  However, have a look at [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build a new path if that's what you need, and you can use [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) to search for a specific file name, or for files matching a pattern, in the desired directory.

**Removing Spaces**

If you have a file name with spaces in it, and you want all spaces removed, you can do

```
string newFilename = oldFilename.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: `int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());` In case when there are more than one `_`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: It may in fact be an error condition if there are more than 2 parts.  Depends on the domain requirements.  Calling Last() may obscure a legitimate error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a regex:

```
var s = @"C:\Uploads\X\X-1\37\Misc_ 319.pdf";
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"^.*?(\d+)(\.\w+)?$");
int i = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
// do something with i
```

It should work with or without an extension of any length (as long as it's a single extension, not like `my file 123.tar.gz`).